# In wagtail, how to include a ForeignKey for a snippet with a panel that lets you add/create new items?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Having a snippet "Scientist" and another snippet "Country". When editing Scientist, it shows a dropdown with all the countries.
I'm trying to find a way to also show an "Add new" so the editor can add a new country directly from the Scientist's change form.

Currently, they should first go to the Country snippet panel, add a new one, and then go back to the Scientist and create the new one.

Here's a simplification of the code:

```py
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("name"),
        max_length=25,
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
    ]


class Scientist(DraftStateMixin, RevisionMixin, ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=25)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("country"),
    ]
```

Scientist is extending `ClusterableModel` because in the real code there's another field that's a `ParentalManyToManyField`.

Using Wagtail 5.0.

Thanks a lot!